# Understanding asymptotic notation homework

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, asymptotic-complexity

This is a problem from Steven Skiena's Algorithm Design Manual book. This is FOR HOMEWORK and I am not looking for a solution. I just want to know if I understand the concept and am approaching it the right way.

Find two functions f(n) and g(n) that satisfy the following relationship. If no such f and g exist, write None.

a)    f(n)=o(g(n)) and f(n)≠Θ(g(n))

So I'm reading this as g(n) is strictly (little-oh) larger than f(n) and the average is not the same. If I'm reading this correctly then my answer is:

```
f(n) = n^2 and g(n) = n^3
```

b) f(n)=Θ(g(n)) and f(n)=o(g(n))

I'm taking this to mean that f(n) is on average the same as g(n) but g(n) is also larger, so my answer is:

```
f(n)=n+2 and g(n)=n+10
```

c) f(n)=Θ(g(n)) and f(n)≠O(g(n))

f(n) is on average the same as g(n) and g(n) is not larger:

```
f(n)=n^2+10 and g(n)=n^2
```

d) f(n)=Ω(g(n)) and f(n)≠O(g(n))

g(n) is the lower bound of f(n):

```
f(n)=n^2+10 and g(n)=n^2
```

Now is my understanding of the problem correct? If not, what am I doing wrong? If it is correct, do my solutions make sense?

Comment: o(n), O(n), Theta(n) and Omega(n) have mathematical definitions that you should know and use. Translating them into simpler notions like f(n)=Theta(g) means "f is on average the same as g" helps intuition, but it's not a valid way to answer questions. In particular, your simpler notions lead you astray -- for example in b (since n+2 is not o(n+10)) and c (since n^2+10 = O(n^2)).

Comment: If this is for homework, why don't you just hand it in to get it marked? You're not supposed to get 100% for every homework assignment - if you're missing some understanding, that's what your teacher is there for. [so] is not here to pre-mark your homework.

Comment: Your answers are not all correct.